# Misplaced values ​in created word table / DataGridView export

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, ms-word, office-interop

[image: second image - export in MS Word table]

[image: input from datagridview]

I need your help, I'm trying to export the content od a DataGridView to MS Word Table using Office `Interop`.
I have a problem, the data in a Word table is mislaced, can someone help me?.

I attached 2 images with input and output and part of my code.

```
Table thirdTable = document.Tables.Add(para3.Range, dataGridViewObjednavka.RowCount, dataGridViewObjednavka.ColumnCount, ref missing, ref missing);
{
  for (int i=0; i<dataGridViewObjednavka.Rows.Count;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<dataGridViewObjednavka.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            thirdTable.Cell(i, j).Range.Text = Convert.ToString(dataGridViewObjednavka.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, I just solved the problem myself, thank you :) :) :)

Comment: Please fix the first image. Judging by the output, word.cell is 1-based. try this: `thirdTable.Cell(i+1, j+1).Range.Text = ...`

Comment: yes, i fixed it about a minute ago :) thank you for reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved problem by myself....Only have to add +1 in thirdTable.Cell(i+1, j+1).......Thank you :)